# Add cut/crop marks to pdf with imagemagick

Tags: linux, macos, pdf, imagemagick, crop

I have a pdf file which is getting generated with Inkscape from SVG and processed with ImageMagick.

Now the PDF is a perfect DINA4 @300 DPI

How can I add some marks around it?

My marks should look like this: http://cl.ly/033g3t2h0U0f/A4_crop.png

And I need to place this over the pdf with 3mm to overlap so it's could be correctly cut. Somehow like this result: http://cl.ly/300F0A402r1D (i don't know if this result is 3mm, is just an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick does this easily.

```
composite -gravity center -density 300 src/in.pdf src/overlay.png out.pdf
```

This is it. Notice ghostscript is required for this, or you'll get this error:

```
composite: no images defined `out.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252.
```

I just added some checks before with `identify` to prove the resolution and size is right otherwise I `convert` the files to the right formats.

Comment: I hope you didn't let the cut marks overlap the actual file? They are supposed to be outside the content of the page.

Comment: If you show your ImageMagick script to generate the PDF, it is probably possible to add the crop marks in all in one go... (without needing another `compose` process).

Comment: @MarkSetchell The problem is, this is only an addon to a closed source software, I have only the possibility to add this as "hook". If it was my software I would implement it directly ;)

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche My coworkers said it should overlap the actual document, currently the cut marks don't overlap (because I think they shouldn't) - But lets wait what the customer want ;)

Comment: They shouldn't overlap. You have the actual page size (A4 in your case). That's called the trim size. Then you should have 3 to 5 mm bleed and all objects coming close to the page edge should actually be outside the page for that amount (to compensate for cutting errors). And your trim marks should be outside the bleed area, so that, even if cutting is done incorrectly, they aren't visible.